# Why is my font-size not working for my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

OK, so I've tried using a live HTML editor, and it worked in there, but it is not working when I open my index.html file. Please show me what I am doing wrong. Here is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
        <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap">
        <!-- Permanent Marker Font -->
        <title>Educational Things</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="container" id="nav-bar">
            <!-- RGH Logo-->
            <div class="container nav-bar-items-left">
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar-items-left">RGH</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Navigation Bar Items -->
            <div class="container nav-bar-items-right">
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar-items-right">Item1</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar-items-right">Item2</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar-items-right">Item3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ads -->
        <div class="container" id="ads">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="left-side-ad">
                    <img src="#" class="left-side-ad" alt="left-side-ad">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="right-side-ad">
                    <img src="#" class="right-side-ad" alt="right-side-ad">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="container" id="main-content">
            <!-- Videos -->
            <div class="container" id="videos">
                <div class="container" id="video01">
                    <a href="#" class="video01">
                        <img src="#" alt="video01" class="video01">
                        <br>
                        <p>video01_title</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav-bar {
    background-color: #DF29CE;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', 'cursive';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 35px;
}

.nav-bar-items-left {
    float: left;
    font-size: 36;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-bar-items-right {
    float: right;
    font-size: 28;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

As you can see, my navigation bar items are supposed to be enlarged, but are staying the same. Am I overlooking something? Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a unit on your font size (eg `36px` or `36pt`), and while the live editor may have been okay with that, most browsers won't change the size of your text without one.

```
.nav-bar-items-left {
    float: left;
    font-size: 36px; // add unit px (pixels)
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-bar-items-left {
    float: left;
    font-size: 36px; // add here too.
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* I had a feeling it was something as simple as that. Thank you so much for replying so fast.